# Does vscode have a custom layout plug-in?

Tags: layout, plugins, outline

Does vscode have a custom **layout plug-in**? The area on the **right side** of my editing area is too empty. If I can drag the **outline** to the area on the right, I think the coding experience will be much better.

[Screenshot of the operation interface 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc7Sx.png)
[Screenshot of the operation interface 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v18Du.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can move the "Botton Panel" to the right
2. Then you can move The "Outline Panel" to the right panel

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But if you do this, the terminal will move to the right side as well.

Comment: @sitdown.liu [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) might be more helpful how you can customise